# Enum case 'case' is not a member of type 'Type'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, enums, contains

I'm a complete new-be in programming and have just started learning swift and iOS development.

The idea is to create a kind of 'set game' (a simple card game).

And I'm trying to implement .contains methods to find if an array contains a particular case but I'm stuck - in line 67 (if case Card.Symbol.oval = element) I get this error: Enum case 'oval' is not a member of type 'Card'

What am I doing wrong?

```
import Foundation

struct  Deck {

private (set) var cards = [Card] ()

    init() {
        for symbol in Card.Symbol.all {
                        cards.append(Card(symbol: symbol))
                    }
            }
    }

struct Card: Hashable {

    static func == (lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
        return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
            hasher.combine(identifier)

    }

    var symbol: Symbol

    enum Symbol: String {
        case squiggle = "■"
        case oval = "●"
        case diamond = "▲"

        static var all = [Symbol.squiggle, .oval, .diamond]

    }

    private var identifier: Int

    private static var identifierFactory = 0

    private static func getUniqueIdentifier() -> Int {
        identifierFactory += 1
        return identifierFactory

    }

    init(symbol: Symbol) {
        self.identifier = Card.getUniqueIdentifier()
        self.symbol = symbol
    }
}

struct SetGame {

    var deck = Deck ()

    lazy var cardsInDeck = deck.cards

    var cardsOpen = [Card] ()

    var cardsChosen = [Card] ()

    mutating func chooseCard(at index: Int) {
        if cardsChosen.count < 3 {
            cardsChosen.append(cardsOpen[index])
        }
        let itemFound = cardsChosen.contains { element in
            if case Card.Symbol.oval = element {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `Card.Symbol.oval = element.symbol`?

Comment: oh, it works! thank you very much! I spent hours in trying to solve it.